# Scala SBT: Triggering an action when local dependencies change

Tags: scala, sbt

In SBT, you can use the "~" mark to trigger actions whenever a source file changes. For example,

```
sbt> ~test
```

will run the unit tests whenever source changes.

Is there any *good* way to trigger actions whenever source changes *or* a local dependency changes? This would be useful when developing two projects simultaneously, where one depends on the other.

I know you can get this behavior by manually specifying a path to a [file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764795/sbt-dependency-on-other-sbt-project-without-publishing) or [the base project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351940/setting-up-sbt-environment-to-hack-on-multiple-libraries-at-once), but that's brittle, and SBT already knows where it's getting its local artifacts, so it's something I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [Triggered Execution](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Triggered-Execution), the `watchSources` task is where you can add additional files to be watched.

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7862872/850196), the `managedClasspath` task provides the part of the classpath that comes from managed dependencies.

Then, the following definition adds the managed test classpath to the files to watch for triggered execution:

```
watchSources <++=
  (managedClasspath in Test) map { cp => cp.files }
```

Define this in each project that you want to trigger on.

Comment: I'm getting an apparent infinite loop with that setting, just using the command "~ compile".

Comment: Do you mean there is a loop in sbt code or it keeps retriggering when nothing changes or something else?  Some other information that might be relevant: what sbt version and what plugins are you using?

Comment: Here's an example: https://github.com/emchristiansen/WatchDependenciesInfiniteLoop

Comment: Ok, thanks for the example.  What happens is that `~` is polling based and will evaluate the `watchSources` task every second (or whatever is configured by `pollInterval`).  In this case, evaluating `managedClasspath` requires evaluating `update`, but `update` doesn't do any work because it is cached.  What isn't cached are the warnings, though.

Comment: The warnings aren't generated in 0.12.3, which is at RC2, so you could switch to that.

Comment: I switched to 0.12.3-RC2, and it's working beautifully, thanks!

Comment: BTW, have you considered making this the default behavior? It seems more natural to me.